# Prevent unwanted form jumping after changing the active control in Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple form containing a button and a textbox with a very high height (which creates a vertical scrollbar in the main form.)
[image]
The button click event is:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button1.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button1.Refresh();
        }
```

The problem is that immediately after clicking the button, the form jumps to the text box:
[image]

A solution to solve this problem is to use the following commands:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int vScoll = this.VerticalScroll.Value;
            button1.Enabled = false;
            this.ActiveControl = null;
            this.VerticalScroll.Value = vScoll;
            this.VerticalScroll.Value = vScoll;
            this.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button1.Refresh();
            button1.Focus();
        }
```

But in real forms, using this method is confusing.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you actually want to block the entire Thread for 2 seconds, or just disable that Button for this duration? -- Anyway, you just need to set `ActiveControl = null` before you disable the Button. Set back the ActiveControl to the Button reference after you re-enable it, eventually. remove all those `Refresh()` things, quite useless

Comment: @jimi Thank you, your solution is correct, but my main request is how to prevent the form's vertical scroll bar from jumping with the least additional command, even when the active control is changed.

Comment: Your Form *jumps* because it's set to AutoScroll. When you disable the Button, the next ActiveControl is the TextBox. If you set `ActiveCntrol = null` beforehand, the  Focus won't be moved to the TextBox. So your code becomes: `ActiveControl = null; button1.Enabled = false; Thread.Sleep(2000); button1.Enabled = true; ActiveControl = button1;`. Use `await Task.Delay(2000)` if you don't want to block the entire UI Thread while the Button is disabled (marking the `button1_Click` handler `async`, of course)